# Understanding the force between two moving charges

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

To understand the attractive and repulsive force between two currents, I am looking at two electrons moving parallel and antiparallel to each other.

How can an attractive (or less repulsive) Lorentz force between two charges and its directional dependence be explained?

I would like to understand this in terms of dynamical effects of the electric field and not in terms of a magnetic field which is the common approach for correctly treating and not further looking at such details.

Comment: read Purcell E&M chapter-4

Comment: Its chapter 5 which provides some ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How can an attractive (or less repulsive) Lorentz force between two charges and its directional dependence be explained?

You can use the fields from the [Lienard Wiechert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation) to calculate the Lorentz force $\vec F = q \ (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$ on each charge.

If you do this there will be a repulsive electric force between the charges and a magnetic force. The magnetic force will be attractive when they are moving parallel and repulsive when they are moving antiparallel.

> I would like to understand this in terms of dynamical effects of the electric field and not in terms of a magnetic field which is the common approach for correctly treating and not further looking at such details.

You can use the [Lorentz transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) to boost to a reference frame where $\vec v=0$ and then use the [Lienard Wiechert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation) to calculate the E field and then calculate $\vec F = q \ (\vec E)$ for the charge at rest. Then repeat for the other charge. It is probably a little more math but it certainly can be done that way if you want.

When you do that the E field in the boosted frame will either be increased or decreased so that the E field force matches the total force that was calculated above.

Comment: And what should I see if I did this?

Comment: @FrankBreitling I added that information to the answer

Comment: Great. Thank you!